# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019) Latex Error: File `size14.clo' not found

Tags: beamer, texlive, ubuntu, texlive-2019

With `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019)` on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` I'm getting the following error with `beamer` slides:

```
Latex Error: File `size14.clo' not found
```

Any hint to solve the problem.

Comment: there is no `size14.clo` in the standard classes. The `extsizes` package includes one,  so perhaps you want to install that, but perhaps it is an error in your document, that is requesting a non standard size?